# Maven Mojo: escape characters in default-value of properties

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

The default-value of a Mojo property starts with:

```
${user.home}
```

I will write the value to a properties file and it should then be replaced at runtime not at build time.

I tried:

```
default-value="${user.home}/..."
default-value="\${user.home}/..."
default-value="\\${user.home}/..."
```

but it always gets replaced with the user.home of the user running the build.

Is there a way to avoid the replacement?

Edit:

The code in question is in a custom Maven Mojo:

```
public class MyCustomMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    ...

    /**
     * @parameter expression="${some-expression}" default-value="\\${user.home}/some-path"
     * @required
     */
    private String userdir;

    ...

    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {

        ...

        Properties configProperties = new Properties();
        configProperties.setProperty(Main.USER_DIR_PROPERTY, userdir);
        Path propertiesFilePath = confPath.resolve(propertiesFileName);
        try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(propertiesFilePath))) {
            properties.store(bos, "");
        }

        ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After it's coming clear that you are talking about the creation of a plugin then...the point is coming that the [default-value](http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html) is intended to be replaced during the build execution of the mojo. I'm not sure what you like to achieve but i think you are mistaking it with expression. Furthermore the idea of a default-value is that it will be replaced incl. the system properties. May be you can give supplemental information to see what you like to achieve.

Comment: I don't understand. The default-value is part of the Javadoc of the Mojo. (The Mojos use Javadoc based annotations.) I want to _write_ it to a properties file later, but it has been replaced before I can write it.

Comment: Can you give the pom and what you exactly called and where the above file is located?

Comment: The default-value is part of a custom Maven Mojo plug-in. See my updated question.

Comment: Why would you like to define something outside the current module via user.home ?

Comment: The custom Mojo creates a properties file. The userdir will be the value for one of the properties I'm writing to that file. It's the place where application data will be stored at runtime. The default value for userdir should start with ${user.home}, e.g. ${user.home}/.myProduct/version

Comment: A Mojo parameter which has a default-value can be overridden but doesn't have to, which is exactly what I want.

Comment: The problem i see is that you are trying to create a mojo which will create information for runtime of the application and not for the build time which i assume that it won't work cause mojo's should write results etc. to the target folder or might be configured via the settings.xml file. I'm not sure what kind of mojo you are trying to create...May be i'm mistaken things, but in my opinion writing to a location outside the current build does not make sense.

Comment: I'm not writing to a location outside the current build. I'm writing some kind of application bundling Mojo, which is more complex than can be done with an assembly. The properties file will be written to something like target/deployment/standalone/conf/config.properties. As usual, this properties file contains some key/value pairs, and one of that values should by default start with ${user.home}, e.g. myApp.userdir=${user.home}/.myProduct/version But only by default, as the user of this plugin should be able to overridde this value in the POM (-> hence a Mojo parameter)